# Custom entity field is missing in Add content form

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

Created a content type '**News**' having fields '***title***', '***body***' and a custom entity field '***Department***'-which will be populated from department vocabulary terms. I can add contents by loging as admin. I can see all the fields for Add '**News**' when I login as admin.
Now I created a role, '**Content Writer**' and given permission to *Add '**News**' Content* and *Edit Own Content*.

From the Navigation menu I can see the add '**News**' form also. But the form is missing the custom entity field '***Department***'. What I did wrong/missed?

Comment: Maybe "Content writer" role must also have permission to add term to the Department vocabulary ? But you should see the term reference field even if it hasn't that permission. In News content type, Department is just a term reference field ?

Comment: @Flo can you post this as answer. This was the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Content writer" role must have permission to add terms to the Department vocabulary, so he can see the field on the creation form.